# I am not able store the input string from Excel into 2-dimensional string

Tags: c++

I am not able to store the string from Excel into a 2-d string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>   
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("input.csv");
    string line,cell;
    string name[5][20];
    string period[5][8];
    string tname;
    int pos, i = 0;

    while(getline(file, line)) {
        stringstream linestream(line);
        int j = 0;
        while(getline(linestream, cell, ',')) {
            if(j == 0)
                name[i][j] = cell;
            else
                period[i][j - 1] = cell;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Oh my... Please fix that indentation. TIA.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c) ?

Comment: Why would name be a 2D array if you are only using name[i][0] ?

Comment: Note that you write to `name` only at position `[i][0]`

Comment: Can you please give sample input (e.g. the content of your `input.csv`)  and the desired mapping into `name` and `period`?

Comment: name 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1  this is the first line there are 70  lines like this the names should be stored in 2d string for further development and the zeros ad ones in a period array

Comment: name[0][20="name"// the name string to be stored and in period[0][0]=0 is to be stored

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a comma-separate file to a string with `ifstream` I think you could not do that.
**Why?**

Say we have this file:

```
one,two,three
four,five,six
seven   ,  eight, nine
ten,    ten,   ten
```

if you use `,` as delimiter with `ifstream` ( getline ) function it first reads `one` then `two` and then `three\nfour` together; because the delimiter is `,` and not `newline`

if you comfortable with using `std::regex` it can be solve easily:

**first off all you need:**

```
std::ifstream input_file_stream( "file" ); // file stream
std::string string[ 4 ][ 3 ];              // row and column
std::regex regex( R"(\s*,\s*)" );          // regex pattern
int row = 0, column = 0;
```

**second step:**

```
// read from a file line-by-line
for( std::string one_line; std::getline( input_file_stream, one_line ); ){

    // regex_token_iterator as splitter and delimiter is `,`
    std::regex_token_iterator< std::string::iterator > first( one_line.begin(), one_line.end(), regex, -1 ), last;

        // loop over each line
        while( first != last ){

            // each time initialize a row
            string[ row ][ column++ ] = std::string( *first++ );
        }

        // for the next row
        ++row;
        column = 0;
}
```

**and finally**

```
for( const std::string& str : string[ 0 ] ) std::cout << str << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';
for( const std::string& str : string[ 1 ] ) std::cout << str << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';
for( const std::string& str : string[ 2 ] ) std::cout << str << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';
for( const std::string& str : string[ 3 ] ) std::cout << str << ' ';

input_file_stream.close();
```

and the output:

> ```
> one two three 
> four five six 
> seven eight nine 
> ten ten ten
> ```